# Orders of elements in multiplicative groups of fields with positive characteristic

Tags: field-theory, modular-arithmetic, positive-characteristic

Suppose that $k$ is a field with positive characteristic $p$. I want to show that for each $x\in k$ the set $\{x^n\colon n\in \mathbb{N}\}$ is finite. My intuition tells me that I should use Fermat's little theorem but I don't know how to reduce it to this case.

I believe there must a really elementary proof of this fact.

Comment: Is $k$ a finite field? Otherwise the claim is not true in general. For instance, consider $k=\mathbb{F}_p(T)$ and $x=T$.

Comment: @carmichael561, ah you're right. I have confused polynomials with polynomial functions... (And the same for rational functions.)